# How to send integer value in a text box which accepts integer only using selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using selenium webdriver and I am using Sendkeys method to set "1" as integer in the text box. But when i click on proceed it reset the text box to 0 as if no valid value.

Manually when i do the same thing ,it is happening.

Later I came to know that Sendkeys("1") method is sending 1 as string not as integer.

How to deal with this thing? One way i found is java script executor.

Is there any other better way?

Looking for positive response

Comment: What language are you using selenium webdriver with? Could you retag your question or add what you have tried?

Comment: I am using C# . I have tried SendKeys Method.

Answer (score 0):

If it is working in manual approach, try this:

```
    Robot rob = new Robot();
    rob.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_1);
    rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_1);
```

I'm working in Java, but in C# should be very similar, maybe even same.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
public void sendKeysINTByJS(WebDriver driver, WebElement element, int attributeValue){
    JavascriptExecutor js = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver);
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value','"+attributeValue+"');", netQtty);
}
```

You can also use this for strings by changing the parameter type.